# Ways of minimizing long code of string replacement

Tags: android, regex, string, replace

Hi this is my code in replacing a characters:

```
string.replace("は", "b");
string.replace("ハ", "b");
```

What I want is to minimize code using OR operator

```
string.replace("は" || "ハ", "b");
```

But it's not working. Is there possible way to minimize the 1st code above? Can you provide some codes or tutorials?

Comment: Look at regex. `([vb])a` to be replaced by `b`

Comment: Hi i just edited my code again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
pattern = "([vb]a)";
string.replaceAll(pattern, "b");
```

**Edit**

It should work the same way so:

```
pattern = "(は|ハ)";
string.replaceAll(pattern, "b");
```

Or as below in one line it would be:

```
string.replaceAll("(は|ハ)", "b");
```

For good tutorials on regex and how it works look here, http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("[vb]a","b");
```

With you new input it would be:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[はハ]", "b");
```

The first expression is called a "regular expression" - a very powerful way to represent string patterns. This one is one of the most simple. Explanation:

```
[]    indicates character class. Without a quantifier (?,*,+,{n,m}), it says
      "Match exactly one character from this list"
```

You can put all characters to be replaced in one string (no need for the `|` character). I think it is the most compact representation of what you are after.

It is well worth studying regex. See excellent primer at http://www.regular-expressions.info . You can practice at http://www.regex101.com